# what is the difference between setState([]) and setState(()=>)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am doing a small React project.
I heard somewhere that using `setState(()=>)` is better than `setState()`.

For instance, `let [count, setCount] = useState(0)`
`setCount(prev=>prev+1)` is better than `setCount(count+1)`
so I kept using the one having arrow function.

But, here in the code, I found that the arrow function one did not work, but the other one worked.

```
const addCard = () => {
    setCards([
      ...cards,
      {
        topic: topicRef.current.value,
        desc: descRef.current.value,
        id: nanoid(),
        done: false,
      },
    ]);

    topicRef.current.value = "";
    descRef.current.value = "";
  };
```

this code works fine, however if I start doing like `setCards(prevState=>[...prevState, {}])`, the first render works OK, but after that, the Ref value does not read the value I put properly. (I used `useRef()` for topic and desc.)

What is the difference between `setState(()=>)` and `setState()`?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 1):

The more classic example is when you use `setInterval` inside the `useEffect`. take a look at the following code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      // setCount((c) => c + 1);
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this case, it renders `0` and then increments the `count` once after one second. The count value will remain at `1` after that.

The reason behind this is that `count` here represents your React state. This is a variable that holds a value. A `closure` is created over the outer scope where count is declared - which is the `App` component itself. Such variables can change value between function calls, but this is where React's **immutability** comes into play.

You can update the state using the second method as follows:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((c) => c + 1); // this will update count value every second
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

There will always be a fresh state for that variable when using this method.

That's why you shouldn't jump into React without learning core JS first. **React is not JavaScript**, but rather a declarative JavaScript library that simplifies some things.

Codesandbox link of the above example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-interval-gi4xl7

Great article by Dan referencing the same topic: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/